# What is the condition of my pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

I am doing bathroom remodeling. Can you tell me how my pipe looks? This house was built in 1980. So about 44 years old. My house has been using water softener for a long time. Does it look still ok? Or should I contact plumber to replace the whole pipeline? The location is southern California.

I will change the shutoff valve, since it looks it needs a replacement.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any concerns in that picture.  Also, why do you think the shutoff valve looks like it needs replacing?  If the valve is able to successfully stop the water flow, then it should be fine.  Though I would suggest putting a cap (or just cover with a piece of duct tape) on top of the open pipe so debris doesn't drop in there during construction.

Comment: 44 years is about mid life for copper pipe.

Comment: No one can assess your pipe from this photo.

Comment: You should call a plumber to do a physical inspection

Comment: Thanks all i will clean the pipe and area   And also thanks for the valve input. They are functioning so i will clean and keep using then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean up the cement dust and debris from around the copper and those pipes are good for service for another 50 years.

Copper ages very well without failing. It is usually something that gets on the copper that degrades the pipe. Keep dissimilar metals and other agents from the pipes and you will be worry free for years.

Answer (score 1):

From the picture, nothing looks particularly troublesome. Clean things up and keep using it. There's no reason to touch the valve unless you're having a problem with it.

One possible failure mode for copper pipe is corrosion/erosion from the inside. A family member went through this a few years back. Either something in their slab or something in their well has been eating the copper pipe away. Their first sign of it was a pipe disintegrating in their hand during some plumbing work. It turned out all the pipe was paper-thin. The end fix was re-plumbing the entire house with PEX.